# How to get input value from child component to my parent component on click of a button?

Tags: reactjs

The child component: Autocomplete.js

```
return (
          <Fragment>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter Locality."
              onChange={onChange}
              onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
              value={this.state.userInput}
            />
            {suggestionsListComponent}
          </Fragment>
        );
```

### In Parent component i need to get value onclick of a button, from input field and show as alert :

```
<Autocomplete
              suggestions = {[
                "A",
                "B",
                "c",
                "d"
                ]}

                />
              </div>
              <div class="input-field third-wrap">
                <button class="btn-search" type="button" onClick={() => {this.showAlert()}}>
                  Search
                </button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a method as a prop that updates a value on the parent component.

On your child component, on your `onChange` I suppose you have something like:

```
onChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
}
```

So you can add, for example on the callback for the `setState` method this:

```
onChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({ value: e.target.value },
  () => {
    this.props.updateValue(this.state.value);
  }); 
}
```

Then, on your parent component, you create the method that's passed on the prop.

```
updateValue = (alertValue) => {
  this.setState({ alertValue });
}
```

You have to pass it on your props like this:

```
<Autocomplete
  suggestions = {[...]}
  updateValue={this.updateValue}
/>...rest of code
```

Then your showAlert will alert `this.state.alertValue`.

Hope this helps :)